# Why does this simple use of JNA cause a fork() on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, fork, jna

Here's a simple use of the JNA library for creating hard links in Java:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public final class HardLink {

    private static final LibC LIBC = (LibC)Native.loadLibrary("c", LibC.class);

    private HardLink() {
    }

    public static void link(File src, File dest) throws IOException {
        if (LIBC.link(src.toString(), dest.toString()) != 0)
            throw new IOException(LIBC.strerror(Native.getLastError()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Attempting to hardlink " + args[0] + " -> " + args[1]);
        HardLink.link(new File(args[0]), new File(args[1]));
    }

    private interface LibC extends Library {
        int link(String from, String to);
        String strerror(int errno);
    }
}
```

When this program is run on Mac OS X 10.7.4 (Lion) using JNA 3.4.0, it does work, but for some reason it is doing a `fork()` - and I say that because it causes the Java icon to bouncy pop-up (appear) in the task bar with "HardLink" in the command bar as the program name.

My question is: why is JNA doing a `fork()` (or is it)? Is there something wrong with this program?

Note: I'm not interested in other ways to hard link files from Java. This is just an example.

Comment: why does the app showing up in the task bar imply that it is forking?  does it show up twice?

Comment: I agree.  You should focus on determining *all* the reasons why the OSX dock might bounce a new icon, *then* determining which of those is *actually* happening.  I think you'll likely find that launching any Java program which loads AWT classes will probably "bump" the dock, and that you'll probably need to explicitly run in headless mode to avoid having JNA load any AWT classes.

Comment: the reason I thought it was forking is that in my real program the bounce occurred long after the program actually started (when the jna operation first happened). headless mode fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JNA loads some AWT classes unless you're running headless.  It's the loading of AWT-related classes (including Swing) which cause the java process to appear in the OSX Dock.

Run your program with -Djava.awt.headless=true.  This will prevent it from showing up in the OSX dock.